# Шифры. Программа

Tags: java, шифрование

Вот это мой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();    
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String User=in.nextLine();  
    hm.put('a', 1);
    hm.put('b', 2);
    hm.put('c', 3);
    hm.put('d', 4);
    hm.put('e',5);
    hm.put('f',6);
    hm.put('g',7);
    hm.put('h',8);
    hm.put('i',9);
    hm.put('j',10);
    hm.put('k',11);
    hm.put('l',12);
    hm.put('m',13);
    hm.put('n',14);
    hm.put('o',15);
    hm.put('p',16);
    hm.put('q',17);
    hm.put('r',18);
    hm.put('s',19);
    hm.put('t',20);
    hm.put('u',21);
    hm.put('v',22);
    hm.put('w',23);
    hm.put('x',24);
    hm.put('y',25);
    hm.put('z',26);

    for (char letter : User.toCharArray()) {
for (char key : hm.keySet()) {
    if (letter == key) {
            System.out.print(hm.get(key));
        System.out.print(" ");


}   
}
```

Он переводит написанный текст в цифровой шифр. Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе чисел, программа переводила введенный текст в буквы?

Comment: Сравнивать по `hm.get(key)` =) предварительно сделав `Integer.parseInt(тутЧислоВведенноеПользователем);`

Comment: у вас цифры в значениях мапы, значит ищите введенные числа в hm.values() и потом возвращайте их ключи. вот только как ваш код будет различать цифры? например введете строку  "12465"?...это 1,2,4,6,5 или, кажем, 12, 46, 5?

Comment: В коду такого не предусмотрено, но разделением между цифрами-буквами будут служить тире.  Я просто не знаю как именно так сделать.

Comment: а зачем здесь вообще мапа? `key - 'a' + 1` делает тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, переводит стрку с цифрами в буквы, только нет пока обратоки ошибок, но с с задачей справляется.

```
public class Main {
    private static Map<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    hm.put('a', 1);
    hm.put('b', 2);
    hm.put('c', 3);
    hm.put('d', 4);
    hm.put('e', 5);
    hm.put('f', 6);
    hm.put('g', 7);
    hm.put('h', 8);
    hm.put('i', 9);
    hm.put('j', 10);
    hm.put('k', 11);
    hm.put('l', 12);
    hm.put('m', 13);
    hm.put('n', 14);
    hm.put('o', 15);
    hm.put('p', 16);
    hm.put('q', 17);
    hm.put('r', 18);
    hm.put('s', 19);
    hm.put('t', 20);
    hm.put('u', 21);
    hm.put('v', 22);
    hm.put('w', 23);
    hm.put('x', 24);
    hm.put('y', 25);
    hm.put('z', 26);
    printText();
}

private static void printValue() {
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user = in.nextLine();
    for (char letter : user.toCharArray()) {
        for (char key : hm.keySet()) {
            if (letter == key) {
                System.out.print(hm.get(key));
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();
}

private static void printText() {
    System.out.println("вводить цифры через пробел");
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] elements = user.toCharArray();
    String current = "";
    for (char element : elements) {
        if (element == ' ') {
            strings.add(current);
            current = "";
        } else {
            current += Character.toString(element);
        }
    }
    strings.add(current);
    for (String element : strings) {
        integers.add(Integer.parseInt(element));
    }

    strings.clear();
    ArrayList<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer element : integers) {
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(element)) {
                result.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Позже может напишу кароче. грязный вариант в общем ), но рабочий.
Цифры вводятся через пробел.